# shortest Path finder in NEO4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, shortest-path

I'm trying to use below method to find the shortest path between two nodes

```
public static PathFinder<Path> shortestPath(PathExpander expander,
                                        int maxDepth,
                                        int maxHitCount)
```

I have created a function, where I'm trying to get only certain number of paths 
and till specific depth.

```
public List<Path> run2(Node start, Node end, int k, int maxLength) {

    List<Path> result = new LinkedList<Path>();
    for (Path path : GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, maxLength, k).findAllPaths(start, end))
    {
        result.add(path);

    }
    return result;

}
```

but when I call this function

```
run2(source, target, 5,5);
```

I get more than 5 paths in many cases. How can I limit this method to return the less than or equal to specific number of paths?